# Transactional Log data size

Tags: database, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion2009

Occasionally *transaction log* file can grow to *4 times* the data size due to a “`re-indexing`” task triggered by `SDL`.
 What are the recommended settings to *avoid* this?

Comment: This question might be better suited to Server Fault than Stack Overflow. In any case, it would help if you could give more details of your problem. For example, which database server are you using. How did you determine that the cause is a re-indexing task? etc. I see the question is tagged as tridion-2011 and tridion2009; which is it?

Answer (score 7):

As suggested in below link, to keep your logging database from growing beyond its capacity you have to refer your database vendor's documentation to learn how to schedule regular cleanups of this database.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_6EF48C80AD0B45FDB607C73EB639603A

Note- Login required to access it.

Comment: The question is not about the logging database, although indeed, good database maintenance is probably what's required.